# Problem with MQTT server: Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds

Tags: c++, arduino-esp8266

I'am hosting MQTT server on rPi, server works fine and i'am able to connect to it using different machine (PC-ubuntu), but arduino(wemos d1 mini) has a problem with that.
I have already set allow_anonymous to true in config file, and run sudo ufw allow 1883.
Nothing seems to work for me :c

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_INA219.h>
#include "arduino_secrets.h"
// Connect to the WiFi
const char* ssid = SECRET_SSID;                          
const char* password = SECRET_PASS;               
//const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.0.158"; //at first was using this 


IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 100); //then switched to this, but with no effect 
IPAddress server(192, 168, 0, 158);
IPAddress mqtt_server = {192, 168, 0, 158};  
 
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
 
const byte ledPin = D4; // digital pin 4 on a weMos D1 mini is next to ground so easy to stick a LED in.
 
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
 Serial.print("Message arrived [");
 Serial.print(topic);
 Serial.print("] ");
 for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
  char receivedChar = (char)payload[i];
  Serial.print(receivedChar);
  if (receivedChar == '1')
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  if (receivedChar == '0')
   digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  Serial.println();
}
 void reconnect() {
 // Loop until we're reconnected
 while (!client.connected()) {
 Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
 // Attempt to connect
 if (client.connect("DUPADUPA")) {
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("connected");
  client.subscribe("real_unique_topic");
 } else {
  Serial.print("failed, rc=");
  Serial.print(client.state());
  Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
  // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
  delay(5000);
  }
 }
}
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 
 client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
 client.setCallback(callback);
 
 pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
 delay(5000);
 digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
 
void loop()
{
 if (!client.connected()) {
  reconnect();
 }
 client.loop();
}
```

Also checked another lib: <ArduinoMqttClient.h>, but the same error appears.

PS: Also tried code from here: https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/uno-wifi-rev2/uno-wifi-r2-mqtt-device-to-device - works for "test.mosquitto.org", but not with rPi ip

Comment: Hi, if you found already your answer, kindly mark the correct answer or close this issue. Thanks

Comment: You never establish a connect with WiFi. Your client run on top of the WiFi.